# Can someone help me understand the datatable Compute function in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

So I have been trying to learn how to use nodes in order to use the tree properties of C1FlexGrid. I am trying to get totals for all the entries in a node. Right now, I am able to build the tree and group by the Group Names, and get a total for the number of rows attached to each node. There is a column named "Charges" that I am trying to total up using the compute method on the DataTable that i used to fill the grid.

I have not been able to find too much information on this, but from what I understand about the compute function is that it takes 2 strings as arguments.

DataTable.Compute(Expression as String, Filter as String)

However, when I try to add something to the filter other than an empty string (""), i get an error that says "ArgumentException: Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String'"

this is the code causing error:
`sumObject = _data.Tables("Results").Compute("Sum(Charges)", "Group Name = Massy")`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is provided by the relevant documentation.